# Как выполнить действие по таймеру?

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно чтобы действие выполнялось через 0.5 секунды.
Например:

```
$('.className').addClass('className2');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один раз

```
setTimeout(function(){$('.className').addClass('className2');}, 500);
```

Много раз

```
setInterval(function(){$('.className').addClass('className2');}, 500);
```

Comment: Тоесть в функции ето будет выглядеть так: function time() {meout(function(){$('.className').addClass('className2');}, 500);}

Comment: Its ALIVE! ALIVE!